# How to properly set up autolayout ios with inside a cell

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have an UITableView and inside this table view im using the following custom cell.

- A view will have some static labels inside
- B view will contain D-E
- View C view will contain some images inside
- D view will contain a label and a small picture
- E view will contain the main Picture of the Cell

I trying to do some sort of post view copying facebook main concept of posts. This cell represent a post and i have some issues with the autolayout concepts , because im really new in objective c and ios9 and i cant make it work properly.

I have two main issues regarding my B view.
First of all , i want to resize my E view to the maximun scalable size of the picture that fits the width of the b view .  (something like facebook pictures that scales properly to the screen of your phone)
Second, there are gonna be posts that are not going to contain B view, because B view represents the image view of the post. I want to delete that view and just keep A/C views. I want my cell to resize acording to the info inside it . I have already add in my code the average of the cell in the uitableview, however i cant mmake it work.

Pd:Sorry about my english

[image: My actual schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully dynamic height for table view cell is achievable by 1) using estimated row height, 2) setting rowHeight to AutoDimension, 3) and most importantly using constraints in your xib/storyboard. The cell can contain buttons/labels or whatever UI components you'd like to have, as long as you constrain them properly, particularly to make sure things are constrained vertically so table view can figure out the cell height.

Take a look at this https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift